# Do triggered abilities still trigger if the creature is tapped?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

For example if [Falkenrath Noble](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=226751) was tapped and another creature dies then would his triggered ability still trigger or only if it was not tapped?

Comment: The thing to remember with Magic is that the wording is very specific for a reason; if a card says whenever it means whenever, if it says tap and do this it can only be activated if the creature can be tapped. For anything from when to play a card to who/what its target can be simply consider the specific wording of a card; if it says whenever creature attacks is means that you only need to declare the attack, if it says whenever creature deals damage it has to deal damage first. Sounds obvious but it’s easy enough to forget.

Comment: You might be being confused with the old magic rules were Artifacts' static abilities were toggled off if they were tapped, but that no longer applies under the new rules, and never applied to creatures!

Comment: @Nick, Side note: Howling Mime still has its original behaviour through a change in wording.

Comment: @ikegami Hmm, I wonder why they kept it for Howling Mine but not Winter Orb?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Whether an permanent is tapped or not has no effect on its abilities. This is the case for abilities of all kinds (static, triggered and activated).

Three things change when a creature is tapped:

- It is considered tapped by anything that cares.
- It cannot be tapped. (Effects instructing to tap the permanent are skipped. Costs consisting of tapping the permanent can't be payed.)
- It cannot attack.

Do note that the first two items can indirectly prevent abilities from triggering ("Whenever an untapped creature dies, ...") or from functioning ("..., tap it. If you do, ...").

Comment: It being tapped does have an influence on its ability if it's an activated ability, as in it cannot activate an activated ability that has `tap` as a cost to activate if it is already tapped.

Comment: @CLockeWork, See update.

Comment: Happy with that @ikegami

Comment: I didn't mean for the rewrite to be so extensive; Glad you like it.